# Returning Azure Blob Stream directly from WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, azure-blob-storage

I am looking to return a stream from Azure Blob Storage directly to the browser via WCF.
Basically I have a REST WCF service and I am looking to have users download files via the service while the files are stored in Azure Blob storage.

In this question

[Returning Azure BLOB from WCF service as a Stream - Do we need to close it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506350/returning-azure-blob-from-wcf-service-as-a-stream-do-we-need-to-close-it)

it does what I like however it downloads the entire file to a new stream first, is there a way to give the blob stream as the return stream from WCF so WCF acts more like a proxy for the stream?

My issue is with large files (> 10MB), I really do not want to download the entire stream from Azure storage before I can start returning it to the user.

The reason I am doing it this way is I am doing some security checks on my user before I will allow access to the file that is stored in Azure Blob Storage, also some of the files could be up to 1GB in size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done something similar where WCF was used to authorize the client (and check the blob still exists and so on). If everything was OK the WCF service returned a URL with a Shared Access Signature - this allowed the client to access the stream directly from storage. Saving the transaction costs of pulling the blob to the wcf role and then streaming from there.

Might this work for you?

Comment: Yes, after some more searching I came to the same conclusion, this is by far a more elegant solution than making a proxy.  Thanks for the confirmation.