# Downloading an Azure blob in chunks using WCF

Tags: wcf, download, azure-blob-storage

I have been asked to provide a WCF service that allows a blob (potentially 1GB) to be downloaded in chunks as an offset `byte[]` for consumption by a Silverlight application. Essentially, the operation will have a parameter for number of bytes to offset and the max number of bytes to return, nothing complex I think.

The code I have so far is:

```
[OperationContract]
public byte[] Download(String url, int blobOffset, int bufferSize)
{
    var blob = new CloudBlob(url);

    using(var blobStream = blob.OpenRead())
    {
        var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        blobStream.Seek(blobOffset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        int numBytesRead = blobStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        if (numBytesRead != bufferSize)
        {
            var trimmedBuffer = new byte[numBytesRead];
            Array.Copy(buffer, trimmedBuffer, numBytesRead);
            return trimmedBuffer;
        }
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

I have tested this (albeit with relatively small files < 2MB) and it does work, but my questions are:

- Can someone suggest improvements to the code?
- Is there a better approach given the requirement?

Answer (score 2):

```
                    using (BlobStream blobStream = blob.OpenRead())
                    {
                        bool getSuccess = false;
                        int getTries = 0;
                        rawBytes = new byte[blobStream.Length];
                        blobStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        int blockSize = 4194304; //Start at 4 mb per batch
                        int index = 0;
                        int documentSize = rawBytes.Length;
                        while (getTries <= 10 && !getSuccess)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                int batchSize = blockSize;
                                while (index < documentSize)
                                {
                                    if ((index + batchSize) > documentSize)
                                        batchSize = documentSize - index;
                                    blobStream.Read(rawBytes, index, batchSize);
                                    index += batchSize;
                                }
                                getSuccess = true;
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                if (getTries > 9)
                                    throw e;
                                else
                                    blockSize = blockSize / 2; // Reduce by half for each attempt
                            }
                            finally
                            { getTries++; }
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could return the blob as a stream instead of a byte array. There is a code sample in a related question here: [Returning Azure BLOB from WCF service as a Stream - Do we need to close it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506350/returning-azure-blob-from-wcf-service-as-a-stream-do-we-need-to-close-it)

Note there are some restrictions on which bindings you can use when you return a stream.

Comment: As mentioned, the requirement is to return the blob in byte[] chunks, not a stream. Or have I misunderstood what you mean?

Comment: why do you need to consume the blob as a byte array instead of a stream?

Comment: I don't. My client has requested this. So presumably they already have a solution set up that requires this. I can only assume that they would like the flexibility to download a blob in parts, not necessarily in the same session.